# How can I get a dictionary of kwargs, while only allowing certain keywords?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, keyword-argument

I am writing a function that needs to take several kwargs, all defaulting to `None`, and store them in a dictionary. It needs to give the normal `TypeError` if called with an unsupported argument. Is there a better way than this?

```py
def my_function(a=None, b=None, c=None, d=None, e=None):
    dictionary = {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c, "d": d, "e": e}
    # ...
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 I guess I could use that to raise the TypeError manually?

Comment: do you care if `my_function()` has a meaningful signature?

Comment: @JonSG yes, that would definitely be good

Comment: How about `dictionary = locals().copy()` then? With the caveat that you have to use it before doing other assignments .

Comment: @JonSG that should work, thank you! I do need to exclude one non-keyword argument, so I guess I could do `dictionary = {key: value for key, value in locals.items() if key != "excluded_argument"}`?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your current approach is intuitive and best, but if you want to make it even easier, you can try [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module.

```py
import inspect


def my_function(a=None, b=None, c=None, d=None, e=None):
    dictionary = inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe()).locals
    print(dictionary)  # {'a': 'x', 'b': None, 'c': 1, 'd': None, 'e': [1, 2, 3]}


my_function(a="x", e=[1, 2, 3], c=1)
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that easier. `inspect.currentframe` has implementation-specific behavior. It also doesn't address OP's comment about needing to exclude one argument.